# Update a column where it is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table Person that contains a column isStaff (bit), that allows NULL values.

The purpose is that this field must contains values 0/1; however, due to lack of application handling of user input in the first place, there are multiple records with the NULL value in this column.

If I try to execute this query:

```
UPDATE Person
SET isStaff = 0
WHERE isStaff IS NULL
```

I get the error:

> *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>   follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is that the actual query you run? There is no sub-query there.

Comment: I wonder if the `Person` table has some sort of ugly trigger on it that's doing an equal comparison against the entire `inserted` table.

Comment: Just tested this, and this could definitely be the cause. What triggers are on the `Person` table?

Answer (score 5):

If that is your query exactly as posted, then I'm inclined to believe you have a trigger on the `Person` table you're not even aware of.

I'm also inclined to believe it's doing something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE SomeOtherTable
SET SomeColumn = 1
WHERE SomeOtherTable.ID = inserted.ID
```

With triggers, the `inserted` table contains **all** records updated, not just a single record, and you would want something like this:

```
UPDATE SomeOtherTable
SET SomeColumn = 1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
```

Of course, this is all speculative until you can confirm whether or not there is a trigger on the table, and if there is, what the trigger is even doing.

Comment: Or they are setting the value to a scalar variable!

Comment: Yeah, that's an equally bad possibility

Comment: YES!!!! LittleBobbyTables, you are genious,I completely forgot to check if the table has some triggers. When I disabled the trigger before this action, everything was fine. Thanks a lot!!!!